# Why there are some forward slash in the error string?

Tags: jestjs

Here is my stdout after I ran my testings.

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "child 'path1' fails because ['path1' is not allowed to be empty]"
    Received: "child \"path1\" fails because [\"path1\" is not allowed to be empty]"

      39 |     } catch (error) {
      40 |       expect(error.name).toBe('ValidationError');
    > 41 |       expect(error.message).toBe("child 'path1' fails because ['path1' is not allowed to be empty]");
         |                             ^
      42 |     }
      43 |   });
      44 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/models/adChannel/googleadwords/AdGroupAd.spec.ts:41:29)
```

As you can see, the `Received` value has forward slash `\`. It doesn't match the `Expected` value.

I think maybe the string is escaped? I expect the string doesn't have `\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Change your `expect` to this:

```js
expect(error.message).toBe('child "path1" fails because ["path1" is not allowed to be empty]');
```

...and it will work.

---

**Details**

JavaScript allows strings to be defined using either single quotes: `'a string'` or double quotes: `"a string"`.

From the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation):

> Unlike some other languages, JavaScript makes no distinction between single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings

...so it doesn't matter which approach you use.

---

Single quotes work fine in a string defined with double quotes:

```js
const singleQuotes = "has 'single quotes' in it";
```

...and the same is true for double quotes in a string defined with single quotes:

```js
const doubleQuotes = 'has "double quotes" in it';
```

---

...but single quotes need to be escaped if they are in a string defined with single quotes:

```js
const singleQuotes = 'has \'single quotes\' in it';
```

...and the same is true for double quotes in a string defined with double quotes:

```js
const doubleQuotes = "has \"double quotes\" in it";
```

---

You are seeing escape characters in the `Jest` output because `Jest` is formatting the output string with double quotes around it so the double quotes within it need to be escaped.